# How to properly implement the Equatable protocol in a class hierarchy?

Tags: swift, subclass, swift3, equatable

I'm trying to implement the `==` operator (from `Equatable`) in a base class and its subclasses in Swift 3. All of the classes will only be used in Swift so I do not want to involve `NSObject` or the `NSCopying` protocol.

I started with a base class and a subclass:

```
class Base {
    var x : Int
}

class Subclass : Base {
    var y : String
}
```

Now I wanted to add `Equatable` and the `==` operator to `Base`. Seems simple enough. Copy the `==` operator signature from the documentation:

```
class Base : Equatable {
    var x : Int

    static func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now for the subclass:

```
class Subclass : Base {
    static override func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

But this results in an error:

> Operator function overrides a 'final' operator function

OK. After some research (still learning Swift 3) I learn that `static` can be replaced with `class` to indicate the type method can be overridden.

So I attempt to change `static` to `class` in `Base`:

```
class Base : Equatable {
    var x : Int

    class func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}
```

But that results in a new error:

> Operator '==' declared in non-final class 'Base' must be 'final'

Ugh. This is far more complicated than it should be.

How do I implement the `Equatable` protocol and the `==` operator properly in a base class and a subclass?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After lots of research and some trial and error I finally came up with a working solution. The first step was moving the `==` operator from inside the class to the global scope. This fixed the errors about `static` and `final`.

For the base class this became:

```
func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x
}

class Base : Equatable {
    var x : Int
}
```

And for the subclass:

```
func == (lhs: Subclass, rhs: Subclass) -> Bool {
    return true
}

class Subclass : Base {
    var y : String
}
```

Now the only part left is figuring out how to call the `==` operator of the base class from the `==` operator of the subclass. This led me to the final solution:

```
func == (lhs: Subclass, rhs: Subclass) -> Bool {
    if lhs.y == rhs.y {
        if lhs as Base == rhs as Base {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

That first `if` statement results in a call to the `==` operator in the base class.

---

The final solution:

Base.swift:

```
func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x
}

class Base : Equatable {
    var x : Int
}
```

Subclass.swift:

```
func == (lhs: Subclass, rhs: Subclass) -> Bool {
    if lhs.y == rhs.y {
        if lhs as Base == rhs as Base {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

class Subclass : Base {
    var y : String
}
```

Comment: Wow. Clever work-around, but is this REALLY what Swift makes us do?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a while since the question is posted, but I hope my answer helps.

TLDR -- Instead of trying to override `==`, you provide a custom comparing method, make `==` call it, and override the custom comparing method if needed.

---

So you said

> All of the classes will only be used in Swift so I do not want to involve `NSObject` or the `NSCopying` protocol.

But if you *were* to subclass `NSObject`, how will you write your custom comparison method? You will override `isEqual(Any?)`, right? And if you try to conform to `Equatable` protocol in your subclass, compiler will complain about "Redundant conformance to protocol `Equatable`" because `NSObject` already conformed to `Equatable`.

Now that gives us some hints about how `NSObject` handles this problem -- it provides a custom comparing method `isEqual(Any?)`, call it inside `==`, and its subclasses can override it if needed. You can do the same in your own base class.

Without further ado, let's do some experiments(in Swift 4). Define some classes

```
class Grandpa: Equatable {
    var x = 0

    static func ==(lhs: Grandpa, rhs: Grandpa) -> Bool {
        return lhs.isEqual(to: rhs)
    }

    func isEqual(to object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard object != nil && type(of: object!) == Grandpa.self else {
            return false
        }
        let value = object as! Grandpa
        return x == value.x
    }
}

class Father: Grandpa {
    var y = 0

    override func isEqual(to object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard object != nil && type(of: object!) == Father.self else {
            return false
        }
        let value = object as! Father
        return x == value.x && y == value.y
    }
}

class Son: Father {
    var z = 0

    override func isEqual(to object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard object != nil && type(of: object!) == Son.self else {
            return false
        }
        let value = object as! Son
        return x == value.x && y == value.y && z == value.z
    }
}
```

And write some test code

```
let grandpa1 = Grandpa()
let grandpa2 = Grandpa()
let grandpa3: Grandpa? = nil
let grandpa4: Grandpa? = nil
let father1 = Father()
let father2 = Father()
let father3 = Father()
father3.y = 1
let son1 = Son()
let son2 = Son()
let son3 = Son()
son3.z = 1

print("grandpa1 == grandpa2: \(grandpa1 == grandpa2)")
print("grandpa1 == grandpa3: \(grandpa1 == grandpa3)")
print("grandpa3 == grandpa4: \(grandpa3 == grandpa4)")
print("grandpa1 == father1: \(grandpa1 == father1)")
print("father1 == father2: \(father1 == father2)")
print("father1 == father3: \(father1 == father3)")
print("son1 == son2: \(son1 == son2)")
print("son1 == son3: \(son1 == son3)")
```

Run it and you should get

```
grandpa1 == grandpa2: true
grandpa1 == grandpa3: false
grandpa3 == grandpa4: true
grandpa1 == father1: false
father1 == father2: true
father1 == father3: false
son1 == son2: true
son1 == son3: false
```

Comment: 1. Your implementation of `isEqual` in the subclasses should be calling `super.isEqual` after checking the properties of just the subclass. A subclass should not do any checking of any properties of its parent classes. 2. Not really related to the question but your GrandPa, Father, Son class hierarchy is backwards. Logically, a Son is not a Father and a Father is not a GrandPa. The Son class should be root class. Father should extend Son and GrandPa should extend Father.

Answer (score 5):

Following the other answers I came up with this:

```
class Base : Equatable {
    var x : Int
    static func == (lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}

class Subclass : Base {
    var y : String
    static func == (lhs: Subclass, rhs: Subclass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.y == rhs.y && (lhs as Base) == (rhs as Base)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? We tried this and our unit tests failed because the superclass's == was called.

Answer (score 0):

Following [rmaddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39909806/1570970), I came up with a guard approach for testing equality:

### Base.swift

---

```
static func ==(lhs: Base, rhs: Base) -> Bool {
    // ensure class properties match
    guard lhs.x == rhs.x else {
        return false
    }

    return true

}
```

### Subclass.swift

---

```
static func ==(lhs: Subclass, rhs: Subclass) -> Bool {
    // ensure base class properties match
    guard lhs as Base == rhs as Base else {
        return false
    }

    // ensure class properties match
    guard lhs.y == rhs.y else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

```